# I have a list of words in ViewBag.word How can I access this ViewBag in View for an AJAX call. I want to access the whole list

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of words in ViewBag.word
How can I access this ViewBag in View for an AJAX call. I want to access the whole list.

Comment: Not clear what you mean? You don't need to make an AJAX call to get values from a ViewBag. The whole point of the ViewBag is that is is available without having to make server calls?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "list of words" you mean `List<string>()`

```
<ul>
@foreach (var word in ViewBag.Word)
{
    <li>@word</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though i find your design a bit weird, but you can achieve this functionality by using

### Hidden input

```
<input id="words" type="hidden" value="@(String.Join(",", ViewBag.Word))">
```

Then you don't really need to use Ajax per se, you can use vanilla js by doing this:

```
var words = document.getElementById("words").value
```